# Representing data in different way dynamicly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this kind of data in excel sheet

[image]

I want to have this presented like this:

[image]

But dynamically. What do I mean with that?
Well if data change in first picture then data should be changed in second.

For example if I add another value entry for `Client2` like this

[image]

Then the data in second table should be updated like this:

[image]

Is this something that is even possible with just using formulas or will I have to do some VBA programming to achieve this?

Comment: PivotTable is what you need. Try it!

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes, with pivot tables i achieved this, thank you very much. If you answer I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PivotTables to manage your data.